# Can we enable https on a single page in windows azure?

Tags: http, ssl, azure

I have website hosted on azure, and I need to make the payment pages use https, but the rest of the pages as http. for local testing I created a self signed certificate and in web role properties > certificates , selected the certificate . then on the endpoints have made it https and associated the certificate. Now when I run the site it runs it as https. Can I run only a few pages in https and the rest on http?

swaraj

Answer (score 1):

Chandermani is right. For details on how to set this all up, http://blog.smarx.com/posts/redirecting-to-https-in-windows-azure-two-methods will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can runs some pages on http and https. For this you need to

1. Create 2 endpoints one for each http and https
2. Associate the certificate with https endpoint

Now you can browse the site in both http and https. Now all links to these payment pages should refer to https urls. 
Also you need to add a IIS url rewrite module to redirect user to https payment pages in case he directly types the http url of the payment pages.